# IQueryable<T>.Include<T, object>>(Expression<Func<T, object>> not working

Tags: c#, iqueryable, navigation-properties

I am trying to load in navigation properties using the IQueryable Include method, however although the expression is correct I am not getting any results

here is the code

```
protected void LoadNavigationProperty(ref IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    if ((query != null) && (navigationProperties != null))
    {
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            query.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

I put a break point on query.Include and checked the data:

```
navigationProperties[0] = { n => n.UserStatus }  
navigationProperties[1] = { n => n.PrivilegeLevel }
```

after stepping past the include line I checked the queries value again and found that it did not include the nav properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Include()` does not change `query` instance, it returns new one. You need to assign it back to `query`:

```
protected void LoadNavigationProperty(ref IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    if ((query != null) && (navigationProperties != null))
    {
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcin explains why it did not work (`.Include(` does modify the query) however I just wanted to give you an alternate way of doing it so you can use the method as an extension method so it could be used in line just like `.Include(` or `.Select(` would.

```
public static IQueryable<T> LoadNavigationProperty(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    if ((query != null) && (navigationProperties != null))
    {
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);
        }
    }

    return query;
}
```